# How do I process an associative array properly in a PDO (or MySQLi) query?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm using MySQLi for a project (but could easily switch to PDO, read the edit at the bottom). What I want is to be able to process an associative array into an mysql query without typing every key/value pair manually. I know that might be simply put, but I'm still in a learning process when it comes to MySQLi/PDO. To make it clear what I mean here is an example:

Let's say I have this associative array:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'Objective',
    'short_name' => 'OB',
    'generation' => 1
);
```

What I want is to create a query like this:

```
UPDATE signals SET ? = ? WHERE sid = '1'
```

And it to become a query like this (or instead of an UPDATE, an INSERT, SELECT etc.):

```
UPDATE signals SET
    name = 'Objective', 
    short_name = 'OB', 
    generation = 1 
WHERE sid = '1'
```

So basically my question is: is this possible with MySQLi or PDO itself? If it's possible how would I have to do this?
I've read on preparing statements before executing, but it's not getting to me yet. Hopefully someone can help me out.

Edit: I'm still very early into the project so i'm also fine with using PDO, but the same question remains. I did look into both PDO and mysqli, and I'm not sure how to do it with PDO either. So for the sake of the question i'll add PDO to as a tag and to the question.

Comment: Seriously, use PDO. It will make your life soooo much easier.

Comment: I should probably add that i'm okay with using PDO, because it's still early in the project. But I'm not sure how to do it there either.

Comment: Do you mean you want the column names to be dynamic, as well as the values?

Comment: Yes. The keys in the above array are the column names, and the values are the data that should be stored in the record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a function that will take an input array and produce something you can drop straight into your query, as long as you are only updating a single table:

```
function array_to_pdo_params($array) {
  $temp = array();
  foreach (array_keys($array) as $name) {
    $temp[] = "`$name` = ?";
  }
  return implode(', ', $temp);
}
```

Now you can perform your PDO query like this:

```
// The data
$data = array(
  'name' => 'Objective',
  'short_name' => 'OB',
  'generation' => 1
);

// The parameter for the WHERE clause
$sid = 1;

// Build the query string
$query = "
  UPDATE `signals`
  SET ".array_to_pdo_params($data)."
  WHERE `sid` = ?
";

// Convert the data array to indexed and append the WHERE parameter(s) to it
$queryData = array_values($data);
$queryData[] = $sid;

$stmt = $db->prepare($query); // Obviously add the appropriate error handling

$stmt->execute($queryData);
```

Comment: Thank you Dave. I love this approach. It's close to what I was about to do: break up the array and build the query manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PDO's execute statement by passing an array of input values, for a prepared query. For reference: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Example:

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of insert values */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => $calories, ':colour' => $colour));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've seen this, but this still requires me to setup an entire query where I have to define atleast each column name. How does this make my life easier?

Comment: If you were looking for an easy way, then think about learning a FrameWork. Because most of the stuff you need would be pre-written as libraries, helpers, etc. Example: CodeIgniter, CakePHP, Zend, etc.. Among them, I have used CodeIgniter and it's pretty easy to learn(as compared to Zend, in my opinion). There is a concept called `ActiveRecord` in CodeIgniter FW. It might help you: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html
Personally, I would always try to write the SQL code by hand instead of the easy way.

Comment: Good to know. I was affraid you would say that haha. I'm not actually affraid of using a framework, but I don't have the time to learn that right now. Plus this project isn't big and a simple PDO based class will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Zend_DB will let you do exactly that.

Tho we created a wrapper over it my work to make it simpler, I really think it's as simple as you can get, and it does all the magical stuff for you.

You really should give it a try; big time saver once you learn it.

Comment: As much as I appriciate your comment I won't do that for this project right now. I will look into it in the future. But right now I'd like to know how to do this the best possible way through MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Your project just started. MySQLi let you pass variables but it won't build the query dynamically. Like the columns name and such, I had a class on my github to do exactly that, but again, it was replaced by Zend when I learned what it was. You could make your own if you are afraid of Zend or other solutions. Why do you think people created them... it has a use.

Answer (score 0):

How about building the query with [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) as follows:

```
$columns = array(
  'name',
  'short_name',
  'generation', ...
);

$data = array(
  'name' => 'Objective',
  'short_name' => 'OB',
  'generation' => 1
);

$to_update = array_intersect_key($data, array_flip($columns));
$update_string = urldecode(http_build_query(array_combine(array_keys($columns), array_fill(0, count($columns), '?')), '', ', '));

try {
 $stmt = $db->prepare(sprintf('UPDATE table SET %s WHERE condition=?', $update_string));
 $result = $stmt->execute(array_values($data));
 
 ...

} catch (\PDOException $ex) { 

}
```

Be sure to have the parameter for the `WHERE` condition at the end of your `$data` array.

Comment: Interesting and slightly odd approach, but I guess it would work. It won't quote column names though, which is a little dangerous.